# Creating Web Services in VS 2005

Tags: web-services, app-code

Why is that Web Service files (.asmx) have their code-behind placed in app_code folder by default unlike the regular .aspx files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally asmx files are more like proxies for business objects and business objects don't belong to Web Site projects. Web service classes should be placed in a different project dedicated in business logic and not in presentation. aspx and aspx.cs on the other hand are complementary files correctly placed inside a web site project as their job is to present the data.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with Web site projects, this is the style Visual Studio uses. It's not the case with Web application projects.